# How can I set variable 'allow_url_fopen' in .htaccess or php file?

Tags: php

How can I turn on `allow_url_fopen` in `.htaccess` or a PHP file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, it can only be set in php.ini (see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)), unless you're using a version of PHP <= 4.3.4.

If you're using a really old version of PHP (and you shouldn't be) then you can set it in PHP using [`ini_set`](https://www.php.net/ini_set).