# add allow_url_fopen to my php.ini using .htaccess

Tags: php

I want to allow `allow_url_fopen` on my server . I have asked my host and they said it can be done with a `.htaccess` file. Can anyone tell me how to go about this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804010/how-can-i-set-variable-allow-url-fopen-in-htaccess-or-php-file

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this, but I don't think it will work because you're not supposed to be able to change this

Put this line in an htaccess file in the directory you want the setting to be enabled:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

Note that this setting will only apply to PHP file's in the same directory as the htaccess file.

As an alternative to using url_fopen, try using curl.

Comment: Hostgator seems to give a 500 server error when you try this.

Comment: 500 server error on Ipage host

Comment: @shadysherif you've probably resolved this a long time ago, but for anyone else reading, for ipage, you can change the php.ini file from the scripted support page.

Answer (score 23):

`allow_url_fopen` is generally set to On.
If it is not On, then you can try two things.

1. Create an `.htaccess` file and keep it in root folder ( sometimes it may need to place it one step back folder of the root) and paste this code there.

   ```
   php_value allow_url_fopen On
   ```
2. Create a `php.ini` file (for update server `php5.ini`) and keep it in root folder (sometimes it may need to place it one step back folder of the root) and paste the following code there:

   ```
   allow_url_fopen = On;
   ```

I have personally tested the above solutions; they worked for me.

Comment: Please use code block

Answer (score 14):

If your host is using suPHP, you can try creating a `php.ini` file in the same folder as the script and adding:

`allow_url_fopen = On`

(you can determine this by creating a file and checking which user it was created under: if you, it's suPHP, if "apache/nobody" or not you, then it's a normal PHP mode. You can also make a script

```
<?php
echo `id`;
?>
```

To give the same information, assuming `shell_exec` is not a disabled function)