# Google Currency Converter has changed its URL but not getting same result

Tags: php, google-search

I have the following code (below) and was using the iGoogle version.

```
   $url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=' . $amount . $from_Currency . '=?' . $to_Currency;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
    $data = explode(' ', $data[3]);
    $var = $data[0];
```

BUT having looked they are using a different URL:

```
  'http://www.google.com/finance/converter?hl=en&a=' . $amount . '&from=' . $from_Currency . '&to=USD';
```

But simply changing the url does not return the required result that i was used to.

Now all i would get is

```
 http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd
```

SO has anyone worked on this latest currency converter URL or have any ideas.  Or a replacement using PHP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to some more in depth looking and rewording of issue found this post. So in a way its a duplicate.  but here is the question:

[Need API for currency converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777985/need-api-for-currency-converting)

I used @hobailey answer for a temporary fix until i can update it to another version or google decide to do a proper api.

```
  $amount = urlencode($amount);
  $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
  $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
  $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
  $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
  $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);  
  $converted_amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, sorry without seeing or using woocommerce/wordpress I cannot help you but I am sure there will be help soon, or post your own question relating to your issue. sorry

Comment: On my server when I use file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance....'), it does not return anything. So what I can do it for working?

Answer (score 4):

Using XPath:

```
function currency($from, $to, $amount)
{
   $content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to);

   $doc = new DOMDocument;
   @$doc->loadHTML($content);
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

   $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;

   return str_replace(' '.$to, '', $result);
}

echo currency('USD', 'EUR', 1); // returns 0.7216
```

Comment: On my server when I use `file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance....')`, it does not return anything. So what I can do it for working?

Comment: @PlanetHackers please ask your host to enable allow_url_fopen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694240/add-allow-url-fopen-to-my-php-ini-using-htaccess If that doesn't work, please check error logs to figure out what's preventing you to access that resource. It could well be that this service is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a class to connect to Google in easier way [here](https://github.com/ojhaujjwal/currency-converter-php).

[currency-converter-php](https://github.com/ojhaujjwal/currency-converter-php)

I hope it should make some aspects easier!

**Edit**:I just knew that Google service was closed this November 2013.

I am gonna have to change it!

**Edit Again**: I have changed Google Api to Yahoo Api and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: Thanks for this nice class, will keep this in mind when i get to update the sotres.

Comment: oops forgot to mention that you would need to rework on that ta little as it uses the OLD google url http://www.google.com/ig/calculator... as google now use 'https://www.google.com/finance/converter...' but its not a case of a simple url change as i thought :-)

Comment: Thanks for telling. I didnt know that before!

Comment: not a problem, it to a client to notice :-) Google hey! Other than the link the diff below is the explode commands as well

Comment: I have changed Google Api to Yahoo Api and it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution. It will also work if your server IP is not able to use google service.

```
<?php
    $from_currency    = 'USD';
    $to_currency    = 'INR';
    $amount            = 1;
    $results = converCurrency($from_currency,$to_currency,$amount);
    $regularExpression     = '#\<span class=bld\>(.+?)\<\/span\>#s';
    preg_match($regularExpression, $results, $finalData);
    echo $finalData[0];

    function converCurrency($from,$to,$amount){
        $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to"; 
        $request = curl_init(); 
        $timeOut = 0; 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
        $response = curl_exec($request); 
        curl_close($request); 
        return $response;
    } 
?>
```

The source reference [Step Blogging](http://www.stepblogging.com/how-to-convert-currency-using-google-api-and-php/)

Comment: The Google Finance API was due to be be shut down on October 20th 2012. However it remained working since then, until the answer is posted. Google Finance is a discontinued service which offers no support.

Comment: Could you please share us some alternate solution.