# How to set allow_url_fopen to true in Shared Hosting?

Tags: php

As it is in shared hosting i don't have access to change allow_url_fopen in php.ini, Is there is any possible way to change it in **Shared Hosting**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add allow_url_fopen to my php.ini using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694240/add-allow-url-fopen-to-my-php-ini-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set it with your php file using `ini_set()` function

for example to set `display_errors`

```
<?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?>
```

check more from official document.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php