# Can't get PHP in_array to work with XML

Tags: php, xml, google-maps

What I'm trying to do is pull specific data from Google Geocoding results in XML form. Eventually what I'm aiming for is a space where the user can enter their zip/postal code and the website will automatically pull their city/state/country/and coords, but right now I'm just testing to see if I can get it to work.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$postcode = 11212; // zip code that will be looked up. Eventually I'll have a user-input the zip code, but for testing purposes this will suffice
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$postcode."&sensor=false"; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
$status = $xml->status;// GET the request status as google's api can return several responses
if ($status=="OK") {
    foreach($xml->result->address_component as $address_component){
        if(in_array("country", $address_component->type)){
            $country = $address_component->long_name;
            continue;
        } elseif(in_array('locality', $address_component->type)){
            $city = $address_component->long_name;
        }
    }
}
echo "$country";
echo "$city";
```

For those who haven't seen the results of the Geocode XML, here's what it looks like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=11212&sensor=false

I've been stuck here for ages and I feel like I'm going insane trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know it's probably something simple, or I'm just making a silly mistake haha, but I figured it was time to ask for help.

So what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks for the help, everyone :)

Comment: The secret to figure this out is .... to look at warnings and errors!
After that you should be able to solve the issue. 
Here's one hint: you are not using in_array() properly, take a look at warning to find out why :)

Comment: Ok, here's more hint, you can easliy typecast an object to array, it's upto you to find out how ;)

Comment: @lihsus thanks for the reply :) I think that's one of the biggest frustrations I've been experiencing - there are no errors or warnings that I can see! When I upload the code to my website it all loads fine, but I just don't get the results that I'm expecting :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [simplexml\_load\_file error in PHP 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335187/simplexml-load-file-error-in-php-5-3)

Comment: @user2631583, ahh okay probably you need to edit your php.ini then. Anyway the error I see is that you are passing `$address_component->type` as an argument to `in_array()`, you need to typecast it to array using `(array) $address_component->type`. Then it should work as expected. But I strongly recommend to configure your php.ini to show errors and warnings. Goodluck!