# Check with PHP if file contains this text

Tags: php

The php function should check if the file index.php contains the CMS link. 
I tried following but it's not working:

```
    <?php
    $file = file_get_contents("./index.php");
    if (strpos($file, "http://www.wordpress.com") !== false) {
        echo "Found";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Not found";
    }
    ?>
```

I am pretty new to PHP.
I have not found the answer using search.

Comment: Use `realpath()` or `file_exists()` to make sure the path you're giving is correct. Other than a possibly incorrect path I cannot see anything wrong here.

Comment: Also confirm that the link in the file is `http://www.wordpress.com` and not `www.wordpress.com`.

Comment: Do you want to search the PHP source or the generated source?

Comment: I want to search the PHP source

Comment: PHP source? You mean the code, and not the webpage generated by the PHP file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("./index.php");
if (preg_match("/http\:\/\/www\.wordpress\.com/", $file)) {
    echo "Found";
}
else {
    echo "Not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: How is it better than `strpos`?

Comment: `preg_match` performs a regular expression, its slow. Better use `strstr` or even better `strpos`.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` — Reads entire file into a string running the following :

```
 $file = file_get_contents("./index.php");
```

Would would result in `RAW PHP CODE` Instead of rendered HTML version and  `http://www.wordpress.com` might even be from database or any other resource

Use use the full HTTP path instead

```
 $file = file_get_contents("http://www.xxxxx.com/index.php");
```

Example

If you have `a.php` file

```
<?php 
    echo "XXX" ; 
?>
```

If you run

```
 var_dump(file_get_contents("a.php"));
```

Output

```
string '    <?php 

        echo "XXX" ; 

    ?>

' (length=31)
```

and

```
   var_dump(file_get_contents("http://localhost/a.php"));
```

Output

```
  string '  XXX' (length=4)
```

Comment: where does it say he wants to load from a remote site?

Comment: it does not have to be a remote site .... just start with `http://localhost` or otherwise

Comment: @JvdBerg: `./index.php` will not parse the PHP file, it will just return you the PHP source.  `http://localhost/index.php` will parse the PHP and return you the generated output.

Comment: @RocketHazmat But who said the OP wants to analyze the output rather than the PHP source? The point is: we are not sure what the question really is.

Comment: Question is `Check with PHP if file contains this text` no mention of parsing php

Comment: @MathieuImbert: True.  Let's see if we can find out :-P

Comment: php source is enough. Index.php does contain the link and not the database or other files.

Comment: Guys when I'm trying to open the index.php I get the message restricted access. I am using joomla 3. So I may need generated code search and not PHP source. Can anybody help?

Comment: You need to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804010/how-can-i-set-variable-allow-url-fopen-in-htaccess-or-php-file &  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694240/add-allow-url-fopen-to-my-php-ini-using-htaccess  @HiddenChampion