# Problems with PHP for a website for a FiveM server

Tags: php, json, fivem, aruba

I have a PHP problem with my web page. I state that I am developing the site for a FiveM server.

In this page I have to enter the number of players and the number of maximum players that the FiveM server can host.

This is what I wrote:

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('http://fivem.lrfreeroamitalia.it:30120/dynamic.json');

    $decode = json_decode($file, true);
    $clients = isset($decode['clients']);
    $svmaxclients = isset($decode['sv_maxclients']);

    echo $decode['clients'] . '/' . $decode['sv_maxclients'];
            
?>
```

The problem with this code is that it gives me this error PHP:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://fivem.lrfreeroamitalia.it:30120/dynamic.json): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /web/htdocs/www.lrfreeroamitalia.it/home/index.php on line 49
```

Port 30120 of the remote server is open.

P.S. I use Aruba.it as a provider

Comment: A connection timeout is usually a network issue. If you’re sure port 30120 is open and accepting connections, then your host might be blocking outgoing traffic on that port. You’d have to check that with them

Comment: @rickdenhaan I tried to disable the firewall of the remote host fivem.lrfreeroamitalia.it, but without success.

Comment: Maybe you need to enable [`allow_url_fopen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804010/how-can-i-set-variable-allow-url-fopen-in-htaccess-or-php-file)

Comment: I did not mean the firewall on the remote host, but on the host that you're performing `file_get_contents()` from. Many hosts only allow *outgoing* traffic *to* ports 80 and 443. I'm not saying that's your issue, it's just one possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

You use cURL to grab contents and display them.

More Documentation on cURL: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://fivem.lrfreeroamitalia.it:30120/dynamic.json',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$obj = json_decode($response);
echo $obj->clients . '/' . $obj->sv_maxclients;
```

Comment: I entered the code you posted here, but it doesn't give any data. the only thing that appears is "/"

Comment: @LuisDeLaVega I would say that you make sure you set `$obj` to `json_decode($response)`. If that still does not work make sure your server can successfully send a GET request to that address.